# Is it possible to specify absolute locations in Print to align the output?

Tags: output-formatting, text

Just wondering about making the output a little neater.
For example:

```
Print["This is a = ", a , ", and this is b = ", ", Sum = ", NumberForm[a+b,3],"\t Calculation 1"];
Print["This is c = ", c , ", and this is d = ", ", Product = ", NumberForm[c*d,3],"\t Calculation 2"];
```

What is the best way to get the "Calculation 1" and "Calculation 2" words to be aligned vertically such that they are directly under each other, i.e., the "C"s start in the same column? I realize that the "\t" does not accomplish this.

Comment: Have you seen [`Grid`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Grid.html)? Also note that you do not need `Print` to view output and that the [semicolon is not what you think it is](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/#18617).

Comment: Thanks. I didn't think of using Grid. I need to read up on the semicolon. I think it is more powerful that I know how to use at the moment,  but I'm carrying over the habit of ending nearly everything in a semicolon from Matlab usage.